# Unable to connect to Remedy AR System server

Tags: java, web-services, remedy

I am sure that I am using the correct connection information:

```
import com.bmc.arsys.api.ARException;  
import com.bmc.arsys.api.ARServerUser;

/**
 * 
 * A class to automate deletion of BMC Remedy incidents after deploying or decommissioning servers
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class BMCIncidentDelete {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        /*
         * Authentication information
         */
        String host = "";
        String server = "";
        String user = "";
        String pass = "";

        ARServerUser ctx = new ARServerUser();
        ctx.setServer(host);
        // ctx.setServer(server);
        ctx.setUser(user);
        ctx.setPassword(pass);
        ctx.setPort(8080);

        /*
         * Verify user or print stack trace if not possible
         */
        try {  
            ctx.verifyUser();
            System.out.println("Connection verified!");
        } catch (ARException e) {  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
ERROR (90): Cannot establish a network connection to the AR System server; Connection refused: connect
```

Anyone with experience with the AR System API see this issue before? https://communities.bmc.com/docs/DOC-17514

Answer (score 1):

This error (Connection refused) indicates that the Remedy server is not reachable from your server on the host and port provided. You can validate by using `telnet`, substituting the hostname for `$host`:

```
$ telnet $host 8080
```

A successful connection should say "Connected to host.", but based on your question you will likely see "Connection refused". Double check the hostname and port number of the Remedy server, and if necessary check that there are no firewalls, etc. between you and the server.